# Designing and implementing iOS UI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

Can someone please recommend to me where I can either learn or find better resources to learn about designing and implementing beautiful iOS UI's?

Comment: a few places to start: https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/  https://developer.apple.com/design/.  But your question is very open-ended.  It's like asking "Where can I learn to paint like Rembrandt"

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't understand your question if it's about UI/UX or UIKit.

If you are asking about UIKit I recommend you to get free UI designs from Google and practice on it and if there is something you can't make, you can search here "Stackoverflow".

I also recommend reading UIKit documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit

And above all, you should read Apple Human Interface Guidelines
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/